# facebook sharing a node gets wrong preview

Tags: social-network

I used the fb js share

```
  $node_link = url('node/32711');
  $output .= '<script 
  src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share"   
  type="text/javascript"></script>';
  $output .= '<a name="fb_share" 
  type="button_count"     share_url="'.$node_link.'"   
  href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php">Share</a>';
  $output .='</div>';
```

It works well on our testing site but when deploying to live it shares the homepage preview and gets 3 images from the homapage not the node image title and preview

so what to do to force previewing that node exactly to be shared rather than the homepage

I used the [FB Debug tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and when changed the node it previews the node but gets an image from the homepage too soo please help

Comment: get cache clear

Comment: I did this more and more I see its something related meta tags and open graph objects

Comment: try this `$node_link = url('/node/32711');`